# Conversion to ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

EDIT: Solution Found!  For anyone looking to do the same thing, I found a better tutorial below:
http://comfreek.blogspot.com/2012/06/actionbars-and-tabs-under-android-2x.html
It is very basic and shows how to use ABS to set up tabs with fragments in case anyone else is interested!

I'm following the tutorial here to implement tabs and fragments: http://www.lucazanini.eu/2012/android/tab-layout-in-android-with-actionbar-and-fragment/?lang=en

I'm having some trouble converting it for usage with older versions of Android; I'm targeting a minimum level of Gingerbread, so I have to use ActionBarSherlock.  I'm getting errors even when I try to copy the TabActionBarActivity.java class that it says to make.  (I also am unsure how to handle the other two classes for the fragments, but I'll deal with those later).

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;



public class TabActionBarActivity extends SherlockActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    String label1 = getResources().getString(R.string.label1);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label1);
    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> t1 = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(t1);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    String label2 = getResources().getString(R.string.label2);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(label2);
    TabListener<Tab1Fragment> t2 = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label2, Tab2Fragment.class);
    tab.setTabListener(t2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}

private class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> 
    implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener{

    private SherlockFragment mFragment;
    private final SherlockActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(SherlockActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
        // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
        // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    } 

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
}
```

I have an error on the two lines that look like:

```
TabListener<Tab1Fragment> t1 = new TabListener<Tab1Fragment>(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);
```

that states "TabListener t1 = new TabListener(this, label1, Tab1Fragment.class);"  I assume this will be cleaned up when the later portion of code is fixed.

The methods that have to do with selecting/unselecting tabs have errors in them, and I'm unsure of how to fix them.  Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Please post the error message(s) you are receiving

Answer (score 1):

just make sure you're importing

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

if your implementing fragment manager  make sure to call it this way

```
FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager();
```

and use this import

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: Thanks, that cleared some issues up.  I still have an error on the line: mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName()); where it says that 'Fragment cannot be resolved.' If I try to import the Fragment from android.support.v4.app, I get a type mismatch.  Any ideas?